# Energy balance turbine

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, potential

In order to evaluate the energy balance of a turbine we use enthalpy. Enthalpy is useful because, at constant pressure, it indicates the total heat exchanged. However, a gas going through a turbine does not hold its pressure constant, so I am not sure why the need to use enthalpy variations as opposed to variations of another thermodynamic potential. May someone explain it in an either intuitive or a rigorous way? Thanks

Comment: If some reference to integral balance equations is needed, have a look here https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/CM/BalanceEquations/main.html and https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/CM/BalanceEquations/integralBalanceEqns.html

Comment: Thanks everybody for the explanations, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Enthalpy is defined as the internal energy of a system plus the work required to push the surroundings out of the way. In a control volume with an inlet and an outlet, the change in enthalpy is the change in internal energy from swapping material, plus the difference between the work done to push the material in (at one pressure, say) and the work that must be done to push the material out (at a different pressure). This parameter can be useful in flow analysis, including some turbine analyses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review the derivation of the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics.  In this version, the work is subdivided into two parts, the work to push material into and out of the system, and the shaft work.  If this is applied to an adiabatic turbine (Q=0) operating at steady state, you get $$0=-[\dot{W}_s+\dot{m}\Delta (Pv)]-\dot{m}\Delta u$$where $\dot{m}$ is the mass rate of flow entering and exiting the turbine, $W_s$ is the rate of doing shaft work, $-\dot{m}\Delta (Pv)$ is the rate of doing work to force the gas into and out of the turbine, and $\Delta u$ is the change in internal energy of the gas per unit mass between the inlet and outlet of the turbine.  Rearranging this equation gives:  $$\dot{m}\Delta h=-\dot{W}_s$$where h is the enthalpy per unit mass of the flowing gas between inlet and outlet of the turbine.  In a turbine, the shaft work is positive which means that the gas enthalpy decreases between the inlet and outlet.

Answer (score -1):

Let's follow a rigorous way, in few steps:

1. integral balance of total energy for the geometric volume inside the machine where the fluid flow
2. manipulation some terms of the integral balance, to make power and **total enthaply** appear
3. introduce some reasonable assumptions to get the simplified desired expression,
   $$ P = \dot{m} \, \Delta h^t \ .$$
   We'll do it only at the end, to emphasize that the process is rigorous, independent from such assumptions until the last stages

[image]

### Integral balance of total energy

Let's write the total energy balance for the fluid medium flowing through a turbine.
Let's call the fluid volume $v_f$, whose boundary $\partial v_f$ is the union of the inflow and outflow manifolds $s_i$, $s_o$, and the solid surface $s_{fs}$, $\partial v_f = s_i \cup s_o \cup s_{fs}$.

The integral form of the total energy balance reads

\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_{v_f} \rho e^t + \oint_{\partial v_{f}} \rho e^t \left(\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u}_b \right) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = \int_{v_f} \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{u} + \oint_{\partial v_f} \mathbf{t_n} \cdot \mathbf{u} - \oint_{\partial v_f} \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ ,
\end{equation}
where the total energy is the sum of the kinetic and internal energy $e^t := e + \frac{|\mathbf{u}|^2}{2}$, $\mathbf{u}$ is the velocity field, $\mathbf{u}_b$ is the velocity of the points of the surface $\partial v_f$, $\mathbf{g}$ is the volume force, $\mathbf{t_n}$ is the surface stresses that can be expressed using the stress tensor $\mathbb{T}$ as $\mathbf{t_n} = \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbb{T}$.
The stress tensor for a fluid can be expressed as the sum of the pressure stress and viscous stress as

$$\mathbb{T} = - p \mathbb{I} + \mathbb{S} \ ,$$

so that the stress vector can be written as $\mathbf{t_n} = - p \mathbf{\hat{n}} + \mathbf{s_n}$.

### Manipulation of the surface terms

**Power of surface stress.** The power of the turbine comes from the contribution of the surface stress. Let's split the integral as the sum of the contributions on the three regions,

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
 \oint_{v_{f}} \mathbf{t_n} \cdot \mathbf{u} & = \int_{s_i} \mathbf{t_n} \cdot \mathbf{u} + \int_{s_{o}} \mathbf{t_n} \cdot \mathbf{u} + \int_{s_{fs}} \mathbf{t_n} \cdot \mathbf{u} = \\
 & = - \int_{s_i} p \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbf{u} - \int_{s_{o}}  p \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbf{u} - \int_{s_{sf}} \mathbf{t_n}_{sf} \cdot \mathbf{u}_s = \\
& = - \int_{s_i} p \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbf{u} - \int_{s_{o}}  p \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbf{u} - P_{sf} \ ,
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
having:

- assumed that the viscous stress is negligible on the inflow and outflow manifolds, $\mathbf{t_n}|_{s_x} = \left( -p \mathbf{\hat{n}} + \mathbf{s_n} \right)\mathbf{t_n}|_{s_x} \sim -p \mathbf{\hat{n}}|_{s_x}$
- identified the last term as the power from the fluid to the machine, through the surface surface stress.

**Total energy flux.** The flux contribution reads
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\oint_{\partial v_{f}} \rho e^t \left(\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u}_b \right) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} & = \int_{s_i} \rho e^t \left(\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u}_b \right) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}  + \int_{s_o} \rho e^t \left(\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u}_b \right) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} + \int_{s_{fs}} \rho e^t \left(\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u}_s \right) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = \\
& =  \int_{s_i} \rho e^t \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} + \int_{s_o} \rho e^t \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ ,
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
having prescribed the velocity of the geometric fluid volume as $\mathbf{u}|_{s_i} = \mathbf{u}|_{s_o} = \mathbf{0}$ on the inflow and outflow manifolds and $\mathbf{u}_b|_{s_{fs}} = \mathbf{u}_s$ (the velocity of the solid walls of the rotor/stator).

Putting everything together in the total energy balance, and isolating the power $P_{sf}$,

\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_{v_f} \rho e^t + \int_{s_i} \rho e^t \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} + \int_{s_o} \rho e^t \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = \int_{v_f} \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{u} - \int_{s_i} p \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbf{u} - \int_{s_{o}}  p \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbf{u} - P_{sf} - \oint_{\partial v_f} \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} 
\end{equation}
and thus, introducing the definition of the **total entalpy**,
$$h^t := e^t + \frac{p}{\rho} = \frac{|\mathbf{u}|^2}{2} + e + \frac{P}{\rho} = \frac{|\mathbf{u}|^2}{2} + h \ , $$
the expression of power becomes
\begin{equation}
  P_{sf} = - \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_{v_f} \rho e^t - \int_{s_i} \rho h^t \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} - \int_{s_o} \rho h^t \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} + \int_{v_f} \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{u} - \oint_{\partial v_f} \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ .
\end{equation}

### Expression of power

Introducing the assumptions of steady regime $\frac{d}{dt} \equiv 0$, negligible volume force $\mathbf{g} \equiv \mathbf{0}$, and negligible heat transfer $\mathbf{q} \equiv \mathbf{0}$, and changing the orientation of the unit normal on the inner manifold (from pointing outwards the turbine geometry $v_f$ to the "flow direction"),the equation eventually becomes

$$
  P_{sf} = \int_{s_i} \rho h^t \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{\tilde{n}}} - \int_{s_o} \rho h^t \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}  \ .
$$

Assuming uniform total enthalpy on the inflow and outflow manifolds, and using the mass integral balance (under the same assumptions: steady regime, $\dots$) to get the mass flow through the machine, $\dot{m}$, the expression of the power becomes

$$  P_{sf} =  h_{i}^t \int_{s_i} \rho \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{\tilde{n}}} - h_{o}^t \int_{s_o} \rho \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = \dot{m} \left( h_{i}^t - h_o^t \right) \ . $$

**Notes.** The most complete expression of power deals with the **total enthalpy**, not only enthaply. Total enthalpy has a kinetic contribution that is not negligible in some applications, dealing with fluids with non-negligible velocity, like applications in aeronautics (compressor/turbines in an airplane engines, since an airliner flies with a cruise speed $\sim 850 \, \text{km/h}$.

Comment: I wonder why, what, and who the fucking hell is this anonymous down-voter, aka sucker

Answer (score -1):

FIG 1 below is an example of the application of the first law to a general open system. FIG 2 narrows the example to adiabatic turbines, compressors, and pumps.

$$\dot W_{OUT}=\dot m(h_{1}-h_2)=-\dot m\Delta h$$

> However, a gas going through a turbine does not hold its pressure
> constant, so I am not sure why the need to use enthalpy variations as
> opposed to variations of another thermodynamic potential.

For an ideal gas it can be shown that $\Delta h=c_{p}\Delta T$ for any process (not necessarily constant pressure).

$$\Delta h=\Delta u+\Delta (PV)=\Delta u+R\Delta T$$

For an ideal gas, any process, $\Delta u=c_{V}\Delta T$

$$\Delta h=(c_{V}+R)\Delta T$$
$$c_{V}+R=c_{P}$$

$$\Delta h=c_{P}\Delta T$$

Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]